# Django can't find static files and template files

Tags: python, django

After I edit my `settings.py`  to  3 files (`base.py` `prod.py` `dev.py`) in directory called settings

It can't find the Django template or static files  (`404 error`)

What should I do ?

**base.py:**

```
DEBUG = FALSE 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ("js", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'js')),
    ("css", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'css')),
    ("images", os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT,'images')),
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS=( os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),)
```

**prod.py:**

```
from .base import *
DATABASES = {   
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': " ",
        'USER': " ",
        'PASSWORD': " ",
        'HOST': "" ,
        'PORT': "5432",
    }
}
```

**wsgi.py:**

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings.prod")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**urls.py:**

```
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
            url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this in production, make sure you run`python manage.py collectstatic` which will store all static files into the directory defined by STATIC_ROOT in you settings.py file. Then to serve these using a web server (like nginx or apache), you just add alias to the directory defined in STATIC_ROOT.

Answer (score 0):

`django.views.static.serve` works only in the development mode (DEBUG = True). See [the warning in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve)

So on production machine you have to [serve static files with the web-server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-from-a-dedicated-server) instead of a django app.